# How to get Intellisense to display the meaning of an enum value

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2005, intellisense

I'm wanting to know to get Intellisense in Visual Studio 2005 to display the meaning of individual enum values for a VB.NET project.  This already happens for enums that are a part of the .NET library.

Is this possible?  If so, how would I need to comment my enums to get this to happen?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In VS 2008 simply use the standard XML commenting syntax. I assume (but have no way of checking) that it's the same in VS 2005?

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Overall description
    ''' </summary>
    Public Enum Foo AS Integer
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Specific value description
        ''' </summary>
        First,
        ''' <summary>
        ''' etc.
        ''' </summary>
        Second
    End Enum
```

Comment: In VB.NET use `'''` instead of `///`

Comment: Thank you @jball, this does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 7):

In C#, you do it like this:

```
enum Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The first value.
    /// </summary>
    Val1,
    /// <summary>
    /// The second value
    /// </summary>
    Val2,
    /// <summary>
    /// The third value
    /// </summary>
    Val3
}
```

So, in VB you would just add the XML comment summary above the enum value.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else finds this and has the same problem...

This doesn't work when you assing values like this, only the first summary will be shown.

```
''' <summary>
''' Overall description
''' </summary>
Public Enum Foo AS Integer
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Specific value description
    ''' </summary>
    First = 0
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Does not show up!
    ''' </summary>
    Second = 1
End Enum
```

Just add an empty row before every new summary and it works:

```
''' <summary>
''' Overall description
''' </summary>
Public Enum Foo AS Integer
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Specific value description
    ''' </summary>
    First = 0

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Does now show up!
    ''' </summary>
    Second = 1
End Enum
```